# Can't get findnext property of range class error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to parse a report in Excel 2007.  It is basically a report of accounting charge exceptions.  The report has sections with a header for each type of exception.  There are types of exceptions that are deleted from the report. I'm using a Do While loop to find each header and if the section needs to be deleted I have it do so.  If nothing needs to be deleted the code works fine, but right after a section is deleted I get an "Unable to get the FindNext property of the Range Class" error.  Here is my code:

```
Sub merge_All_Section_Headers()
' Description:
' The next portion macro will find and format the Tranaction Source rows in the file
' by checking each row in column A for the following text: TRANSA.  If a cell
' has this text in it, it is selected and a function called merge_text_cells
' is run, which performs concatenation of each Transaction Source header row and
' deletes the text from the rest of the cells with broken up text.
'
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
Range(lastRow & ":" & lastRow).Delete

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape

With ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
   Dim searchString As String

   searchString = "TRANSA"

   'The following sets stringFound to either true or false based on whether or not
   'the searchString (TRANSA) is found or not):
   Set stringFound = .Find(searchString, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)

   If Not stringFound Is Nothing Then

      firstLocation = stringFound.Address

      Do
         stringFound.Select

         lastFound = stringFound.Address

         merge_Text_Cells

         If ((InStr(ActiveCell.Text, "CHARGE FILER") = 0) And _
             (InStr(ActiveCell.Text, "CREDIT FILER") = 0) And _
             (InStr(ActiveCell.Text, "PA MIDNIGHT FINAL") = 0) And _
             (InStr(ActiveCell.Text, "BAD DEBT TURNOVER") = 0)) Then

            section_Del 'Function that deletes unwanted sections

         End If

         Range(lastFound).Select

         Set stringFound = .FindNext(stringFound)

       Loop While Not stringFound Is Nothing And stringFound.Address <> firstLocation

     End If

End With
  '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  'BELOW CONTAINS THE CODE THAT WORKS:
   Sub merge_All_Section_Headers()
   ' Description:
   ' The next portion macro will find and format the Tranaction Source rows in the file
   ' by checking each row in column A for the following text: TRANSA.  If a cell
   ' has this text in it, it is selected and a function called merge_text_cells
   ' is run, which performs concatenation of each Transaction Source header row and deletes
   ' the text from the rest of the cells with broken up text.
   '
   lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
   Range(lastRow & ":" & lastRow).Delete

   ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape

   With ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
       Dim searchString As String
       Dim arrRangesToDelete(0 To 9) As Range

       searchString = "TRANSA"

       'The following sets stringFound to either true or false based on whether or not
       'the searchString (TRANSA) is found or not):
        Set stringFound = .Find(searchString, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)

        If Not stringFound Is Nothing Then

           firstLocation = stringFound.Address

           counter = 0

           Do

              stringFound.Select

              lastFound = stringFound.Address

              merge_Text_Cells

              If ((InStr(ActiveCell.Text, "CHARGE FILER") = 0) And _
                  (InStr(ActiveCell.Text, "CREDIT FILER") = 0) And _
                  (InStr(ActiveCell.Text, "PA MIDNIGHT FINAL") = 0) And _
                  (InStr(ActiveCell.Text, "BAD DEBT TURNOVER") = 0)) Then

                  firstRowOfSection = ActiveCell.Row

                  lastRowOfSection = (ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1).Address).End(xlDown).Row + 2)

                  Set arrRangesToDelete(counter) = Range(firstRowOfSection & ":" & lastRowOfSection)

                  counter = counter + 1

              End If

              Range(lastFound).Select

              Set stringFound = .FindNext(stringFound)

           Loop While Not stringFound Is Nothing And stringFound.Address <> firstLocation

        End If

   End With

   For i = 0 To counter - 1

       arrRangesToDelete(i).Delete

   Next i

   Range(firstLocation).Select

End Sub
```

So, the array works and does the job, without destroying any objects. I still want to try the Union method and see if I can get it to work, which would be cool as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code falls over as the range object in `StrFound` has been destroyed - so it `Is Nothing` when you go to apply

There are a couple of alternatives to the error handling proposed bu Juri (which if you do use you should reset immediately)

- Add all the sections to be deleted to a new range with `Union` then delete this range in a single shot outside the loop. I have an example in my article here in my article [Using Find and FindNext to efficiently delete any rows that contain specific text](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2919-Using-Find-and-FindNext-to-efficiently-delete-any-rows-that-contain-specific-text.html)
- Move your delete code after the `.FindNext` rather than before it, and add a simple test to see if `stringfound` exists before running your `Section_Del` code

**Union approach**

```
Sub UnionAPp()
Dim c As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500")
    Set c = .Find(2, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstaddress = c.Address
        Set rng1 = c
        Do
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Set rng1 = Union(rng1, c)
        Loop While c.Address <> firstaddress
    End If
    MsgBox "Your working range is " & rng1.Address
End With
End Sub
```

So you could modify the standard Excel help for `FindNext` from

**standard**

```
Sub TestInit()
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500")
    Set c = .Find(2, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Value = 5
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

**new**

```
Sub TestA()
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500")
    Set c = .Find(2, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Value = 5
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then c.Clear
            'your code: If Not StrFound Is Nothing Then Call Section_Del
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Brettdj! I like the idea of checking that it exists before deleting, but how do I reset stringFound after it gets destroyed? Thanks!

Comment: I think I see what you're saying.  Use union to add ranges that need to be deleted together in the loop and then delete that range outside the loop.  So there'd be no need to delete while inside the loop.

Comment: @LawrenceKnowlton Yes - it is normally cleaner to work on a one result range rather than run every time a check is flagged. The article link shows an example of this.

Comment: I tried doing union, but could not get it to work. So, my next thought was to gather the ranges into an array in the loop.  The problem now is how do I access that array so I can then delete the actual ranges (which are row ranges)?

Comment: `Union` approach added above. Working back from the array is difficult - it is possible but hard. Better to work with the range

Comment: Finally! I got it to delete the ranges in the array! I tried doing union, but could not get it to work. So, my next thought was to gather the ranges into an array inside the loop. Then, outside the original loop, I created another loop to delete each range in the array.

Comment: I will try to get the Union approach to work. Does union work with non contiguous ranges? The sections are not always contiguous that need to be deleted. Will Union work with that?

Comment: If you have troubles with non contiguous ranges then loop through each `Area` of the `Range` and then kill that ie  'For each ra in rng1.Areas` etc

Answer (score 0):

If all occurencies are deleted, `Findnext` should give an error.

A line

```
On Error Goto ExitLoop
```

should be added before `Set stringFound = .FindNext(stringFound)`.

A line

```
ExitLoop:
```

should be added after `Loop While...`

Comment: Hi Juri, your solution only keeps the error message from displaying. Now it keeps breaking out of the loop after a section is deleted. Can you think of another way to avoid exiting the loop until all sections are processed? Thanks!

Comment: I guessed that the error was because of the last instance to find was deleted by `section_Del`. However, if `section_Del` doesn't work at all, one should look into the code of the function.

Comment: Yes the problem was that, although section_Del was working as it was meant to, the stringFound object was being destroyed in the process.